# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing an AI that will predict its own one by one - for example, an array [22,1,456,2] is given, and it will predict [33,1,455,3].
But when I run this code:

```
from music21 import converter, instrument, note, chord
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

notes = []
file = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\titanic_guitar.mid"

# Получаем все ноты и аккорды из файла
midi = converter.parse(file)
parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)


if parts:
    notes_to_parse = parts.parts[0].recurse()
else:
    notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes
for element in notes_to_parse:
    if isinstance(element, note.Note):
        # Добавляем "ноты, типа ля2-до3"
        notes.append(str(element.pitch))
    elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
        # Добавляем аккорды
        notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.pitches))

print(notes)
note_to_int = {note: number for number, note in enumerate(sorted(set(notes)))}
for i in range(len(notes)):
    notes[i] = note_to_int.get(notes[i])
print(notes)
X = np.expand_dims(notes, axis = 0)
print(X)
y = np.array([1,1,1])
y = y.reshape(1,-1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, X.shape[1])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )
r = model.fit(X,
              y,
              epochs=5
             )
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 168)
```

What is the problem?

Do you have working options?

Answer (score 1):

reshape your data by using

```
.resape(-1,1)
```

Comment: How? I don't have got array i've got an expand_dims. Can you show me were i need to do it?